# Will we ever end up in the black hole?

Tags: galactic-dynamics

Since we are spiraling around the black whole will we spiral into the black hole?

Comment: I think this has really already been asked and answered http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/500/orbiting-around-a-black-hole

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to predict since the Milky Way galaxy and the Andromeda galaxy are going to collide in about 5 billion years. Since we cannot predict the gravity influences so far in advance, it is impossible to say.

There are 3 outcomes of this collision. The solar system falls into the black hole, the solar system goes into orbit in the new galaxy, or the solar system get propelled away from the new galaxy.

Comment: By that time, our solar system will have gone beyond expiration date.